# how to function to next and previous button function in UIPageViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have used UIPageViewController and my code is below.

```
class HomeViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    private var pageViewModel :PageViewModel!

    init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options: [String : Any]? = nil, withViewModel viewModel:PageViewModel) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: options)

        pageViewModel = viewModel
        print(pageViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray)

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

   l!

    var pageControl = UIPageControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        createPageViewController()


        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.74, green: 0.69, blue: 0.78, alpha:1.0)
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.62, green: 0.31, blue: 0.82, alpha:1.0)
        self.pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.93, green: 0.86, blue: 1, alpha:1.0)
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray! .count

        print(self.pageControl.numberOfPages)
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)

    }

    fileprivate func createPageViewController() {

        if (pageViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)! > 0 {
            let firstController = getItemController(0)!
           let startingViewControllers = [firstController]


            self.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    fileprivate func setupPageControl() {



    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as! HomeController

        if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {


        print(pageViewController)


        let itemController = viewController as! HomeController

        if itemController.itemIndex+1 < (pageViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)! {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
        }



        return nil
    }
//fileprivate

  func getItemController(_ itemIndex: Int) -> HomeController? {

        if itemIndex < (pageViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)! {

                          let homeViewModel :HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel(withmodel:pageViewModel.datafordisplay(objectatindex: itemIndex))
                let ViewController = HomeController(nibName: "HomeController", bundle: nil, withViewModel: homeViewModel)
            ViewController.itemIndex = itemIndex
            return ViewController
        }

        return nil
    }



    func getItemController1(_ itemIndex: Int) {

        if itemIndex < (pageViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)! {

            let homeViewModel :HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel(withmodel:pageViewModel.datafordisplay(objectatindex: itemIndex))
            let ViewController = HomeController(nibName: "HomeController", bundle: nil, withViewModel: homeViewModel)
            ViewController.itemindex1 = itemIndex
            print(ViewController.itemindex1)


      //      pageViewController(homeViewModel, viewControllerAfter: ViewController.itemindex1)

        }


    }


    func currentControllerIndex() -> Int {


        let pageItemController = self.currentController()

        if let controller = pageItemController as? HomeController{


            print(controller.itemIndex)

            return controller.itemIndex
        }

        return -1
    }

    func currentController() -> UIViewController? {



        if (self.viewControllers?.count)! > 0 {
            return self.viewControllers![0]
        }

        return nil
    }


    func pageViewController(
        _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
        willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers:[UIViewController]){
        if let itemController = pendingViewControllers[0] as? HomeController {
            self.pageControl.currentPage = itemController.itemIndex
        }
    }

}
```

And the HomeController as below:-

```
class HomeController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate{

    var itemIndex: Int = 0
    var i = 0
    var j = 0
    var k = 0


    var itemindex1 :  Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!






    private var homeViewModel :HomeViewModel!


    @IBOutlet weak var tableview1: UITableView!

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, withViewModel viewModel:HomeViewModel) {

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        homeViewModel  = viewModel
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var screen3: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var screen1: UIView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




           name.delegate = self





        if itemIndex == 0{
            screen1.isHidden = false
            tableview1.isHidden = true
            screen3.isHidden = true

        }



        else if itemIndex == 1{
            screen1.isHidden = true
            tableview1.isHidden = false
            screen3.isHidden = true


        }

        else if itemIndex == 2{

               screen1.isHidden = true
               tableview1.isHidden = true
               screen3.isHidden = false
               submitbutton.isHidden = false


        }



     //   self.restaurantname.text = homeViewModel.homeModel.name

              // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }





    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {


    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {


        return true;
    }

    func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       // tableView.reloadData()
        return true;
    }


    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {




            let names =  name.text
            self.homeViewModel.name = names

            self.homeViewModel.isValidInput(Input:self.homeViewModel.name!)


        */

             return true;
    }

    /*
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {




        */

        return true


    }
    */


    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder();


        name.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Here i have 1 UIViewController.And inside UIViewController i have

2 UIView and 1 tableview.The names are screen1 and screen3 is UIView and one tableview .

Here according to the coding i got the scrolling the view with using of UIPageViewController.

Now i need two buttons in the UIPageViewController as next and previous button.So when i click the next button i need to scroll the view and it should display the tableview.Again on next button it should scroll to the screen3.How to do Also the UIPageControl also should move .How to solve .

And for previous button same function but backward .How to do ?

Comment: how to solve the issue?

Comment: Long story short, you need 2 buttons to switch controllers in UIPageViewController?